# How to find the modulus of a complex components?

Tags: complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

Firstly I am not a student of mathematics just because right now I am doing a course related to complex variable I am having interest on learning things in a proper way .

Suppose,
$Z=1+i$ and $C=1-i$

what is the value of $|Z^C|$ ?

Using principle value of $z^c$:=$exp(c logz)$

First i have found the value of logz for which i have used the formula $logz=lnr+i(argz)$.

After simplification ,

$exp(ln\sqrt2 +\frac{\pi}{4}+i\frac{\pi}{4}-iln\sqrt2)$

What should be the next step ?  or is there any other way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$ and we only care about the modulus, we ignore the imaginary parts of the exponent. The answer is $e^{\ln\sqrt2+\pi/4}=\sqrt2e^{\pi/4}$.